# Random element order in XML document using XML::LibXML

Tags: perl, csv, xml-libxml

I have a Perl script that reads a simple `.csv` file like below-

```
"header1","header2","header3","header4"
 "12","12-JUL-2012","Active","Processed"
 "13","11-JUL-2012","In Process","Pending"
 "32","10-JUL-2012","Active","Processed"
 "24","08-JUL-2012","Active","Processed"
 .....
```

The aim is to convert this `.csv` to an `.xml` file something like below-

```
<ORDERS>
  <LIST_G_ROWS>
     <G_ROWS>
         <header1>12</header1>
         <header2>12-JUL-2012</header2>
         <header3>Active</header3>
         <header4>Processed</header4>
     </G_ROWS>
     <G_ROWS>
         <header1>13</header1>
         <header2>11-JUL-2012</header2>
         <header3>In Process</header3>
         <header4>Pending</header4>
     </G_ROWS>
....
....
   </LIST_G_ROWS>
</ORDERS>
```

I know that there is `XML::CSV` available in CPAN which will make my life easier but I want to make use of already installed `XML::LibXML` to create the XML, instead of installing `XML::CSV`. I was able to read the CSV and create the XML file as above without any issues, but I am getting a random order of the elements in the XML i.e. something like below. I need to have the order of the elements (child nodes) to be in sync with the `.csv` file as shown above, but I am not quite sure how do go around that. I am using a `hash` and `sort()` ing the hash didn't quite solve the problem either.

```
<ORDERS>
  <LIST_G_ROWS>
     <G_ROWS>
         <header3>Active</header3>
         <header1>12</header1>
         <header4>Processed</header4>
         <header2>12-JUL-2012</header2>                          
     </G_ROWS>
 ......
```

and so on. Below is the snippet from my perl code

```
use XML::LibXML;
use strict;

my $outcsv="/path/to/data.csv";
my $$xmlFile="/path/to/data.xml";
my $headers = 0;
my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0', 'UTF-8');
my $root = $doc->createElement("ORDERS");
my $list = $doc->createElement("LIST_G_ROWS");
$root->appendChild($list);

open(IN,"$outcsv") || die "can not open $outcsv:  $!\n";
while(<IN>){    
    chomp($_);
    if ($headers == 0)
    {
        $_ =~ s/^\"//g;     #remove starting (")
        $_ =~ s/\"$//g;     #remove trailing (")
        @keys = split(/\",\"/,$_);  #split per ","
        s{^\s+|\s+$}{}g foreach @keys;  #remove leading and trailing spaces from each field
        $headers = 1;       
    }
    else{   
        $_ =~ s/^\"//g;     #remove starting (")
        $_ =~ s/\"$//g;     #remove trailing (")    
        @vals = split(/\",\"/,$_);  #split per ","
        s{^\s+|\s+$}{}g foreach @vals;  #remove leading and trailing spaces from each field

        my %tags = map {$keys[$_] => $vals[$_]} (0..@keys-1);                   
        my $row  = $doc->createElement("G_ROWS");
        $list->appendChild($row);
        for my $name (keys %tags) {
            my $tag = $doc->createElement($name);
            my $value = $tags{$name};
            $tag->appendTextNode($value);               
            $row->appendChild($tag);
        }
    }
}
close(IN);

$doc->setDocumentElement($root);
open(OUT,">$xmlFile") || die "can not open $xmlFile:  $!\n";
print OUT $doc->toString();
close(OUT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could forget the `%tags` hash entirely.  Instead, loop over the indices of `@keys`:

```
for my $i (0 .. @keys - 1) {
    my $key   = $keys[$i];
    my $value = $values[$i];
    my $tag   = $doc->createElement($key);
    $tag->appendTextNode($value);
    $row->appendChild($tag);
}
```

That way, the ordering of your keys is preserved.  When a hash is used, the ordering is indeterminate.

Comment: I will try this, thanks. But I am wondering how the null values in the `@vals` would behave here.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is far more involved than it needs to be. For convenience and reliability you should use [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV) to parse your CSV file.

The program below does what you need.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;
use XML::LibXML;

open my $csv_fh, '<', '/path/to/data.csv' or die $!;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new;
my $headers = $csv->getline($csv_fh);

my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0', 'UTF-8');
my $orders = $doc->createElement('ORDERS');
$doc->setDocumentElement($orders);
my $list = $orders->appendChild($doc->createElement('LIST_G_ROWS'));

while ( my $data = $csv->getline($csv_fh) ) {

  my $rows = $list->appendChild($doc->createElement('G_ROWS'));

  for my $i (0 .. $#$data) {
    $rows->appendTextChild($headers->[$i], $data->[$i]);
  }
}

print $doc->toFile('/path/to/data.xml', 1);
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ORDERS>
  <LIST_G_ROWS>
    <G_ROWS>
      <header1>12</header1>
      <header2>12-JUL-2012</header2>
      <header3>Active</header3>
      <header4>Processed</header4>
    </G_ROWS>
    <G_ROWS>
      <header1>13</header1>
      <header2>11-JUL-2012</header2>
      <header3>In Process</header3>
      <header4>Pending</header4>
    </G_ROWS>
    <G_ROWS>
      <header1>32</header1>
      <header2>10-JUL-2012</header2>
      <header3>Active</header3>
      <header4>Processed</header4>
    </G_ROWS>
    <G_ROWS>
      <header1>24</header1>
      <header2>08-JUL-2012</header2>
      <header3>Active</header3>
      <header4>Processed</header4>
    </G_ROWS>
  </LIST_G_ROWS>
</ORDERS>
```

---

**Update**

Without the exotic options that `Text::CSV` provides, its functionality is fairly simple if its options are fixed. This alternative provides a subroutine `csv_readline` to replace the `Text::CSV` method `readline`. It works mostly in the same way as the module.

The output of this program is identical to that above.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

open my $csv_fh, '<', '/path/to/data.csv' or die $!;

my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0', 'UTF-8');
my $orders = $doc->createElement('ORDERS');
$doc->setDocumentElement($orders);
my $list = $orders->appendChild($doc->createElement('LIST_G_ROWS'));

my $headers = csv_getline($csv_fh);

while ( my $data = csv_getline($csv_fh) ) {

  my $rows = $list->appendChild($doc->createElement('G_ROWS'));

  for my $i (0 .. $#$data) {
    $rows->appendTextChild($headers->[$i], $data->[$i]);
  }
}

print $doc->toFile('/path/to/data.xml', 1);

sub csv_getline {
  my $fh = shift;
  defined (my $line = <$fh>) or return;
  $line =~ s/\s*\z/,/;
  [ map { /"(.*)"/ ? $1 : $_ } $line =~ /( " [^"]* " | [^,]* ) , /gx ];
}
```

Comment: Every Installation of a new Perl Module on our AIX production server costs money and is "sometimes" expensive (even though it might be as simple as a single command). I can Install as much PMs as possible on my local machine and write a much simpler code, but there are restrictions when I run the code on the server, which is the reason why I am more willing to re-use existing installed modules (on the server). It works for me, and is efficient too, but thanks for the suggestion. If i were to go for a new PM then I would have opted for `XML::CSV`.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that the simplification was entirely due to the use of `Text::CSV`. Picking the right methods from `XML::LibXML` has provided most of the reduction. Fundamentally the functionality of `Text::CSV` is straightforward, and I have added to my answer a solution using a short subroutine that does the same job without using the module. I have looked at `XML::CSV` and note that it subclasses `Text::CSV`, so if you were to get it installed you would have two modules for the price of one! But `Text::CSV` is essential where CSV files are at all common.

Answer (score -2):

Seems like something that `XML::LibXml` is an overkill for, just use `XML::Simple` and build the proper hash which will describe that XML structure, than dump it with `XMLOut` to an XML file